# Use grabcut algorithm to separate the saliency areas

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk3Fo.png)I first detected the saliency of the image and then used the grabcut algorithm to segment the saliency targets. However, the result was a salient image but did not segment the saliency map. The error was as follows: error :-5 image mush have cv_8uc3 type in function grabcut, this is my source code, what should I do?`

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from scipy import misc
    import argparse
    import sys,cv2
    from skimage.io import imread, imsave
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg 

g_mean = np.array(([126.88,120.24,112.19])).reshape([1,1,3])
output_folder = "./test_output"

def rgba2rgb(img):
         if img.ndim == 2:
            img = gray2rgb(img)
         elif img.shape[2] == 4:
            img = img[:, :, :3]
         upper_dim = max(img.shape[:2])
         if upper_dim > args.max_dim:
            img = rescale(img, args.max_dim/float(upper_dim), order=3)
     return img

def largest_contours_rect(saliency):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(saliency * 3,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    return cv2.boundingRect(contours[-1])

def refine_saliency_with_grabcut(img, saliency):
    rect = largest_contours_rect(saliency)
    bgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65),np.float64)
    fgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65),np.float64)
    saliency[np.where(saliency > 0)] = cv2.GC_FGD
    mask = saliency
    cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 1, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
    mask = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
    return mask

def backprojection_saliency(img,args):  
        saliency =main(args)
        #cv2.imshow("original", saliency)
        #saliency=mpimg.imread('alpha1.png')
        img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 232))
    mask = refine_saliency_with_grabcut(img, saliency)
        #misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,'flowers2.png'),result)
    return mask

def main(args):

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.mkdir(output_folder) 

    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = args.gpu_fraction)
        with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options = gpu_options)) as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./meta_graph/my-model.meta')
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./salience_model'))
        image_batch = tf.get_collection('image_batch')[0]
        pred_mattes = tf.get_collection('mask')[0]

        if args.rgb_folder:
            rgb_pths = os.listdir(args.rgb_folder)
            for rgb_pth in rgb_pths:
                rgb = misc.imread(os.path.join(args.rgb_folder,rgb_pth))
                if rgb.shape[2]==4:
                    rgb = rgba2rgb(rgb)
                origin_shape = rgb.shape
                rgb = np.expand_dims(misc.imresize(rgb.astype(np.uint8),[320,320,3],interp="nearest").astype(np.float32)-g_mean,0)

                feed_dict = {image_batch:rgb}
                pred_alpha = sess.run(pred_mattes,feed_dict = feed_dict)
                final_alpha = misc.imresize(np.squeeze(pred_alpha),origin_shape)
                misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,rgb_pth),final_alpha)
        else:
            rgb = misc.imread(args.rgb)
            if rgb.shape[2]==4:
                rgb = rgba2rgb(rgb)
            origin_shape = rgb.shape[:2]
            rgb = np.expand_dims(misc.imresize(rgb.astype(np.uint8),[320,320,3],interp="nearest").astype(np.float32)-g_mean,0)

            feed_dict = {image_batch:rgb}
            pred_alpha = sess.run(pred_mattes,feed_dict = feed_dict)
            final_alpha = misc.imresize(np.squeeze(pred_alpha),origin_shape)
            misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,'alpha.png'),final_alpha)
                        #rgbs = mpimg.imread('flower1.jpg')
                        result=refine_saliency_with_grabcut(rgb, final_alpha)
                        misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,'segmentation.png'),result)
                        #cv2.imshow("original", final_alpha)
                        #plt.imshow(final_alpha)                       
        return final_alpha;

def parse_arguments(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--rgb', type=str,
        help='input rgb',default = None)
    parser.add_argument('--rgb_folder', type=str,
        help='input rgb',default = None)
    parser.add_argument('--gpu_fraction', type=float,
        help='how much gpu is needed, usually 4G is enough',default = 1.0)
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(parse_arguments(sys.argv[1:]))``
```

Comment: Give your original image and salience map.

Comment: @Silencer I have put the original and the saliency map in my question above

Comment: then you want to crop the flower?

Comment: @Silencer Yes,When I use grabcut split, it shows the following error:error :-5 image mush have cv_8uc3 type in function grabcut

Comment: You should feed "3-channels" to `cv2.grabCut`

Comment: Yes, how to modify my code?Can you give me some suggestions

Comment: This is my result using threshed(not your saliency map): https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Xxd.png I'll write my answer.

Comment: Can you provide your source code? thank you very much

Comment: @Silencer Can you provide your source code? thank you very much

Comment: I wrote the answer. (I forget which parameter I adjusted, so the result is a slighted different with the upper. )

Answer (score 2):

I use the threshed binary image to find the max contour, then create a mask. Do grabcut using this mask.

The source:

[image]

And the result is like this:

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.27 15:26:53 CST
# 2017.11.27 16:37:38 CST

import numpy as np
import cv2

## read the image(读取图像)
img = cv2.imread("tt04_flower.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#displaySplit(img)

## threshed(阈值化)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## findContours(查找轮廓)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

## sorted by area(按照面积排序)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

## get the maximum's boundinRect(获取最大边缘的外接矩形)
cnt = cnts[-1]
bbox = x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

## create mask(创建掩模)
mask = np.ones_like(gray, np.uint8)*cv2.GC_PR_BGD
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, cv2.GC_FGD, -1)

## 使用 grabcut 分割
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
rect = bbox

cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype("uint8")

grabcut = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

## save and display
cv2.imwrite("flower_res.png", grabcut)
cv2.imshow("(1) source", img)
cv2.imshow("(2) grabcut", grabcut)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---